# Webscraping prices from McMaster-Carr

Tags: python

Having an issue pulling prices of parts from McMaster-Carr. No errors, but in the output the price is not displayed anywhere.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.mcmaster.com/91251A051/"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

price = soup.find_all('div')
print(price)
```

Comment: You are aware that webscraping commercial websites is, generally speaking, a violation of terms of service and could get you blocked or sued, right?

Comment: I suspect that `mcmaster.com`, like many websites, makes extensive use of Javascript to update pages dynamically *after* they are initially loaded into your browser. Extracting data from this sort of page often requires substantially more work, and may ultimately require using an *actual browser* to parse the page (via a tool like [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro)).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it might be good to check the `/robots.txt` on the website that you want to scrap.
most of the websites don't like scrapers and they block them immediately.
And I highly suggest you to read this [blog post](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-prevent-getting-blacklisted-while-scraping/).